# are there any python web framework support "flush"?

Tags: python, comet

in php there is a `flush` function, which is used to push content to client, meanwhile keep current connection.

i look into flask, didn't found any function like it. are there any python web framework support flush ?

ps: the reason to use flush is to implement comet through iframe stream, though ajax long poll can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Streaming Contents](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/streaming/?highlight=flush)